# How to separate select Queries from a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a text file which have some queries and text merged, i want to separate those 
Exa: myfile.txt

```
my file abc.........

select * from exa

my file ABC Again.........
```

I only want to extract queries from file, and queries might be multi-lined.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using ms sql server

Comment: That's a huge task. You'll need a SQL grammar with support for all possible SQL syntax, at least.

Comment: Yep Any examples

Comment: what is the separator between texts ? coma separated ?

Comment: nothing just query key words are seprators

Comment: Go search the internet for some sort of sql parser package for the development environment of your choice. What you won't find is support for this in tsql - if that is what you are assuming. Whether those will work with random text scattered throughout is something you will need to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit difficult task. You can dump the data of the text file in a SQL Server table and use `LIKE` operators to get the data having SQLs (`INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE` AND `DELETE`).